# Drano and Bleach reaction?

Tags: reactivity, reaction-control, cleaning

I’m not sure if anyone can answer this but I might’ve messed up, or I’m just overreacting.

My bathtub has been clogged for about a month now and I used a splash of Drano to see if it would do anything, which I know is less then what’s instructed. However, since it’s a super slow draining tub because of said clog, is it possible that the drano would react to bleach used to clean my tub from a week ago? I’m asking out of pure anxiety. Yes there’s been water moving through the drain overtime but I wasn’t sure if any of the chemicals could be sitting in with the clog and I didn’t know at the time that bleach and drano are a huge no, and I wasn’t sure if they could meet and mix over time.

Bleach used: https://stopandshop.com/groceries/laundry-paper-cleaning/household-cleaners/bathroom-cleaners/bathroom-tub-shower-cleaners/clorox-foamer-bathroom-bleach-trigger-spray-30-oz-btl.html Active Ingredient: Sodium Hypochlorite - 2.40%. Other Ingredients - 97.60% Draino used is mostly Mostly sodium hydroxide (NaOH). https://www.whatsinsidescjohnson.com/us/en/brands/drano/drano-liquid-clog-remover

Before anyone asks, yes I did call poison control. The person I spoke with didn’t seem too concerned and just told me to ventilate the room just in case but I’d like a second opinion because of the possibility of the chemicals sitting I the drain. I wasn’t sure if the bleach would be diluted by now or not.

Comment: It is always good to list composition of commercial products, so readers need not to search for it

Comment: Bleach used: https://stopandshop.com/groceries/laundry-paper-cleaning/household-cleaners/bathroom-cleaners/bathroom-tub-shower-cleaners/clorox-foamer-bathroom-bleach-trigger-spray-30-oz-btl.html Active Ingredient: Sodium Hypochlorite - 2.40%. Other Ingredients - 97.60% Draino used is mostly Mostly sodium hydroxide (NaOH). https://www.whatsinsidescjohnson.com/us/en/brands/drano/drano-liquid-clog-remover

Answer (score 1):

Both bleach and Drano would coexist  well, in fact bleach solutions contain some hydroxide to stabilize them.

Both are washed away by water, so a week interval would separate them, even if they would react with each other.

Bleach must not come in contact with acids. That would lead to production of poisonous gaseous chlorine. But again, a week apart would separate them. The former would be long time away when the latter arrives.

Comment: So even with a clogged drain, there wouldn’t be a chance of anything being left behind? I’m mostly worried about the gases coming out of nowhere, and I’ve read there’s a possibility of explosions. 
I’m certainly no chemist, my anxiety has just been racing for the past few hours.

Comment: No, these 2 products cannot evolve poisonous gas. Bleach does not have much use for clogged drain. Sodium hydroxide based products do (best if solid, poured by hot water and staying there at least overnight do).